# Jekyll and github pages: Sass Indenting at the beginning of the document is illegal

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have an existing `Jekyll` project that works fine locally. When I deploy it to github and trying to use github pages, it gives me an error:

```
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Sass encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/styles.sass':
                Indenting at the beginning of the document is illegal. on line 2
```

The contents of `assets/css/styles.sass` is the next:

```
---
---
@import "style"
```

If I remove `---` marks at the start of the file, github pages now builds the site, but I am losing all css support, as `styles.css` is no longer generated

I unfortunately know nothing of how `Jekyll` works so I am completely lost